# XNA - How to scale sizes and speeds for a minimap?

Tags: c#, xna, minimap

I'm recreating the arcade game StarGate, and I need to create a minimap. But I'm having problems scaling the minimap textures to fit in the radar box, and ontop of that, making sure the speed of the scrolling for the main map and mini map are proportional.

My textures are sized below:

1. Entire side scrolling map: 4800 x 620
2. Screen Size 960 x 720

StarGate screen shot below:
[image]